# How to resolve Unable to merge dex

Tags: java, android, build.gradle, build-dependencies, gradle-dependencies

When I was compile my application so I got below error like,

> Error:Execution failed for task
>
> ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

I add the  **multiDexEnabled true**  in my app.build file but still getting same issue. how can I resolve this error.

Here below my app.build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.rutunjay.retrofit_example"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}}

dependencies {

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"}
```

Comment: clean and rebuild,
Invalidate cache and restart

Comment: **ps remove compile please...it will removed by the end of this year..**

Comment: Ok... its working right now thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use latest [`Dependencies` for `Lifecycle`, including `LiveData` and `ViewModel`.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components)

Try this

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"
```

than **`Clean-Rebuild- Run`** your project

Comment: Thank You @Nilesh Rathod ... Now error is resolve and application is  working fine.

Comment: @Raj happy to help u